# convergence of infinite integral

Tags: calculus

Given f(x) continuous in $[0,\infty)$, and $$\int_0^\infty \left|f(x)\right|dx ~, ~ \int_0^\infty f^4(x)dx$$
converges, prove that $$\int_0^\infty f^2(x)dx$$
converges.

My motivation is to show that:

If $0 \le f(x) \le 1$ than $$f^2(x) \le \left|f(x)\right|$$

If $1<f(x)$ than $$f^2(x) < f^4(x)$$

By applying the comparison rule to both cases i can conclude that $f^2(x)$ converges.

How can i show this formally? dividing to sections?
Is this the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. You can divide into sections or note that in both cases $f^2 \le f^4 + |f|$ (as $f^4, |f| \ge 0$).

Comment: An improved version $f^2 \leq f^4 + \frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}|f|$ holds, too.

Comment: And, in general, $f^2 \leq A f^4 + B |f|$ as soon as $A^{1/3}B^{2/3}\geq \frac{1}{2^{1/3}+2^{-2/3}}$ as a consequence of the Young's inequality.